# VideoView scroll play previous video's audio when scroll and go to next video

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-videoview

```
private final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    int currentPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int newPosition) {
        FragmentLifecycle fragmentToShow = (FragmentLifecycle) viewPagerAdapter.getItem(newPosition);
        fragmentToShow.onResumeFragment();
        FragmentLifecycle fragmentToHide = (FragmentLifecycle) viewPagerAdapter.getItem(currentPosition);
        fragmentToHide.onPauseFragment();
        currentPosition = newPosition;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {


    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

private void DeleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {
            child.delete();
            DeleteRecursive(child);
        }

    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

When i scroll half previous video playing and also next video start playing but i want like instagram when previous video getout from screen then next video play, any Idea or code? please suggest.

Comment: Use their onPause and onResume i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it with create CustomViewPager.